# How to handle class object with circular references?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I am thinking about simple problem. I have given an class for example `Model`

```
class Model {
    constructor(parameters = {}) {
        this.id = parameters.id;
    }
}
```

so as you can see we can create new `Model` objects like: `let model = new Model()`. More complex example would look like this:

```
//we have some data given from API maybe?
let parameters = {id: 1};
let model = new Model(parameters );
```

And here we are at the point where i started to wander **What if the object with given `id` already exists** ?

The question is **what pattern should i use to instantiate object with given `id` only once?**

Let's go further: what if we will get nested objects *with circural references* ? Let assume we got another class called `AnotherModel` and our code looks like:

```
class Model {
    constructor(parameters = {}) {
        this.id = parameters.id;
        this.anotherModel= nulld;

        if (parameters.anotherModel) {
            this.anotherModel= parameters.anotherModel instanceof AnotherModel
                ? parameters.anotherModel
                : new AnotherModel(parameters.anotherModel);
        }
    }
}

class AnotherModel {
    constructor(parameters = {}) {
        this.id = parameters.id;
        this.models = [];

        if (parameters.models) {
            for (let i = 0; i < parameters.models.length; i++) {
                let model = parameters.models[i];
                model.anotherModel= this;
                this.models.push(new Model(model));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So `AnotherModel` contains a collection of `Model`s and `Model` object contains reference to `AnotherModel`.

What is the **nice way** to resolve this issue ? What we want to achive is to have only one object with the same id.

What i was thinking is to do some kind of ObjectPool where i will store all objects for given class or classes and when new object is instantiated our pool would create a new one if it does not exist or return the existing one?

But here is a little disadventage, if for example we already have written some code we would have to refactore and change the way we instatiate them from `new Model()` to `ObjectPool.get(Model, parameters)`?

What are your ideas ?

Comment: In your scenario above, is an instance of `AnotherModel` created first? Or can instances of both `Model` and `AnotherModel` be created individually? I'm not sure if I understand the way your code should work.

Comment: individually, doesnt matter if we first create a `AnotherModel ` or `Model`

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but is it necessary for both components to keep a reference to each other? Especially this line makes little sense to me: `: new AnotherModel(parameters.anotherModel);` (creating `AnotherModel` from the Model without passing in the `Model` itself)

Comment: becouse the idea is that we get some data form API for example and, it can be a verry different situations, for example we will get `AnotherModel` with it `Model`'s then it is easier to crate `model` objects in `AnotherModel` constructor dont you think ? We can also download data separtely for example 2 `AnotherModel`s and what if they have in collection the same `Model` ? we dont want to create same model object again

Comment: Nothing prevents the constructor from using using an object pool. There's no need to rewrite existing code.

Comment: Yes right but this is ok for nexted objects then and what about the object created ? What if it already exist ? We can't use `new AnotherModel()` we also ahve to use pool here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an object pool (either on the class or outside of it) to keep track of your instances. By defining it in the constructor, you can still instantiate models with:

```
new Model();
new AnotherModel();
```

If the `id` already exists in the pool, you can just return the existing instance.

Outside of the class:

```
const modelPool = {};

class Model {
    constructor(parameters = {}) {
        if (modelPool[parameters.id] instanceof Model) {
            return modelPool[parameters.id];
        }

        modelPool[parameters.id] = this;

        this.id = parameters.id;
        this.anotherModel= null;

        // ...
    }
}

const anotherModelPool = {};

class AnotherModel {
    constructor(parameters = {}) {
        if (anotherModelPool[parameters.id] instanceof AnotherModel) {
            return anotherModelPool[parameters.id];
        }

        anotherModelPool[parameters.id] = this;

        this.id = parameters.id;
        this.models = [];

        //...
    }
}
```

Or as a (non-enumerable, non-writeable, non-configurable) property on the class (not the instance):

```
class Model {
    constructor(parameters = {}) {
        if (Model.pool[parameters.id] instanceof Model) {
            return Model.pool[parameters.id];
        }

        Model.pool[parameters.id] = this;

        this.id = parameters.id;
        this.anotherModel= null;

        //...
    }
}

Object.defineProperty(Model, 'pool', {
    value: {}
});

class AnotherModel {
    constructor(parameters = {}) {
        if (AnotherModel.pool[parameters.id] instanceof AnotherModel) {
            return AnotherModel.pool[parameters.id];
        }

        AnotherModel.pool[parameters.id]

        this.id = parameters.id;
        this.models = [];

        //...
    }
}

Object.defineProperty(AnotherModel, 'pool', {
    value: {}
});
```

As added by @Vardius, one can also create a pseudo-abstract class (as JS does not have abstract classes) which can be extended from. Using [`new.target.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target), a namespace within the pool of the abstract class can be created:

```
class Entity {
    constructor(parameters = {}) {
        if (Entity.pool[this.constructor.name] && Entity.pool[this.constructor.name][parameters.id] instanceof Entity) {
            return Entity.pool[new.target.name][parameters.id];
        }
        Entity.pool[new.target.name][parameters.id] = this;
    }
}
Object.defineProperty(Entity, 'pool', {value: {} });
```

Comment: what about if i create an abstract class `AbstractModel` and will define property `pool` just for this class and then all other models will extend it. will it work ?

Comment: i would have to define matrix then to store also `constructor.name` for multiple classes

Comment: Probably not, because `pool` should not be an instance (`this.pool`) or prototype (`AbstractModel.prototype.pool`) property. If it were an instance property, it would not work as it would be created for every instance. Unless you can write to the pool as a property on the `AbstractModel` class in the `AbstractModel` constructor and keep a namespace for all the childclasses.

Comment: here is example of mine:  http://pastebin.com/PMjUA3rf 

`export class Entity {

    constructor(parameters = {}) {
        if (Entity.pool[this.constructor.name] && Entity.pool[this.constructor.name][parameters.id] instanceof Entity) {
            return Entity.pool[this.constructor.name][parameters.id];
        }

        Entity.pool[this.constructor.name][parameters.id] = this;
    }
}

Object.defineProperty(Entity, 'pool', {
    value: {},
    writeable: true,
    configurable: true
});`

Comment: if you think its ok, include it in your answer for future use

Comment: I've added your code to the answer, although I have replace `this.constructor.name` with `new.target.name`, which is more idiomatic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept the answer. Otherwise, let me know what is missing. Thank you.